# Keep in csr_matrix per row the 6 biggest elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a Python `scipy` `csr_matrix` as follows.

```
A = csr_matrix(np.random.choice(a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                                p=[0.35, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15], 
                                size=[10, 12]))
```

A dense representation would be:

```
[[0 2 1 2 1 0 2 0 4 2 1 2]
 [0 0 1 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 4 0]
 [1 3 3 2 1 1 3 0 0 4 2 0]
 [4 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 3 0 3]
 [3 0 3 1 1 3 0 3 4 4 4 0]
 [0 4 0 3 0 4 4 4 0 0 3 2]
 [0 3 0 0 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 1 2 0 4 1 3 2 1 0]
 [0 2 0 4 1 1 1 3 4 2 1 1]
 [0 2 3 0 3 0 4 2 3 0 4 1]]
```

Now, I want per row to keep the six biggest elements, and set the rest to zero. If there are multiple elements equal, It doesn't really matter which one is selected to stay and which one is set to zero, as long as there are only six non-zero elements per row. We can e.g. say that elements with lower indices stay. The expected outcome of the matrix above would then be (manually made):

```
[[0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 4 2 0 2]
 [0 0 1 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 4 0]
 [1 3 3 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 2 0]
 [4 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 3 0 3]
 [3 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 4 4 4 0]
 [0 4 0 3 0 4 4 4 0 0 3 0]
 [0 3 0 0 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 1 2 0 4 0 3 2 0 0]
 [0 2 0 4 1 0 0 3 4 2 0 0]
 [0 2 3 0 3 0 4 0 3 0 4 0]]
```

I can think of a way to achieve this by looping over the rows, but the real matrix in question is huge, so I would prefer to keep loops to a minimum. Does anyone have a hint how to start tackling this problem?

**EDIT**

The following code snippet does exactly what I want, but is terribly inefficient. Transforming the 3000 x 300 matrix in this way takes 9.3 seconds.

```
from timeit import timeit
import warnings

from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, SparseEfficiencyWarning

import numpy as np


__updated__ = '2015-03-12'


def random_csr_matrix():
    np.random.seed(1)
    A = csr_matrix(np.random.choice(a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                                    p=[0.35, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15],
                                    size=[3000, 300]))
    return A

def keep_top_N_in_csr_matrix(A, N):
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', SparseEfficiencyWarning)

#     print ('\nBefore:')
#     print (A.todense())


    N_rows = A.shape[0]
    for i in range(N_rows):
        row = np.squeeze(np.asarray(A.getrow(i).todense()))
        A[i, :] = keep_top_N_in_np_array(row, N)

#     print ('\nAfter:')
#     print (A.todense())

def keep_top_N_in_np_array(A, N):
    assert (A >= 0).all(), 'All elements shall be nonnegative'

    for _ in range(N):
        i_max = A.argmax()
        A[i_max] = -A[i_max]
    A = np.array([-i if i < 0 else 0 for i in A])

    return A

def doit_once():
    A = random_csr_matrix()
    keep_top_N_in_csr_matrix(A, 6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (timeit(doit_once, number=1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

A = numpy.random.randint(5,size=(10,15))
s = A.shape
print A

ind = np.argsort(A)[:,:s[1]-6]
rows = np.arange(s[0])[:,None]

A[rows,ind] = 0
print A
```

Output:

```
[[4 3 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 0 4 3]
 [2 2 4 1 3 2 1 4 3 3 4 1 0 0 1]
 [2 3 3 0 4 0 2 3 3 1 0 1 3 3 0]
 [1 0 0 1 4 1 0 0 4 2 2 3 2 1 0]
 [4 2 1 4 4 1 3 0 3 0 2 2 3 1 0]
 [0 0 0 4 2 1 0 3 0 2 3 3 0 0 3]
 [0 2 2 4 2 3 2 3 3 2 0 4 4 1 2]
 [4 0 0 2 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 2 1 4 3]
 [1 0 2 0 0 4 4 3 3 4 2 0 2 1 0]
 [0 4 0 1 0 3 4 3 2 2 2 3 0 1 2]]

[[4 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 4 3]
 [0 0 4 0 3 0 0 4 3 3 4 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 3 0 4 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 4 2 2 3 2 0 0]
 [4 0 0 4 4 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 3 0 0]
 [0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 0 2 3 3 0 0 3]
 [0 0 0 4 0 3 0 3 3 0 0 4 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 4 4 4 0 0 4 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 4 4 3 3 4 0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 4 0 0 0 3 4 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 2]]
```

Comment: This is answer does not apply for the csr_matrix type.

Comment: This looks good! There is a small modification necessary: the matrix A is a csr_matrix, so must first be converted to a dense matrix. This might make it possible to even come up with a speedier algorithm. However, this algorithm takes 0.25 seconds vs my 9.05 seconds on a 3000x300 matrix.

Comment: @physicalattraction : How 'sparse' is your starting matrix really? If it is rather dense then the `numpy` solution is probably as fast as the `scipy.sparse` solution. However, it occurred to me that you rather start with a dense matrix and the goal is to make is sparse by keeping the 6 largest numbers per row.

Comment: @physicalattraction : Improved the `numpy` solution. On the level of `scipy.sparse` I can't improve anything since I'm not familiar with it

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. Time goes down from 0.26 seconds to 0.23 seconds; not impressive, but nice. About sparsity: I have several matrices. I see one here that is 6500 x 1500 with 20,000 nonzero elements (0.2%), and another one with the same dimensions with 750,000 nonzero elements (7.7%).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that operates on each row in the `csr_matrix`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import *
import scipy as sp

A = csr_matrix(
    np.random.choice(a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                     p=[0.35, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15],
                     size=[10, 12])
)

B = A.copy()
print A.todense()

for i in range(10):
    # Get the row slice, not a copy, only the non zero elements
    row_array = A.data[A.indptr[i]: A.indptr[i+1]]
    if row_array.shape[0] <= 6:
        # Not more than six elements
        continue

    # only take the six last elements in the sorted indeces
    row_array[np.argsort(row_array)[:-6]] = 0

print 'A_mod: ', A.todense()
print 'B: ', B.todense()
print B.todense() - A.todense()
```

In each iteration in the loop you don't get a copy of each row but a reference. So the modifications to `row_array` will also change the corresponding row in sparse matrix `A`. You can tweak the row operation in the loop to meet more specific criteria.

**Update:**

With inspiration from the other answer, `argsort` was used instead or `sort`. After this tweak only six elements will remain in the sparse matrix.

Comment: As it is right now, it has the possibility of allowing more than six nonzero elements per row, if there are multiple elements with the same value as `row_array_sorted[-6]`. I am trying to rewrite it now.

Comment: @physicalattraction, that is correct. However, you can modify the row in the sparse matrix as a numpy array which simplifies life a bit.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.argsort(row_array)[-6:]` ? `np.argsort(row_array)[:-6]` returns all results withou top 6

Comment: Nice answer. Time complexity can be improved using `np.argpartition` as we do not care of sorting: `row_array[np.argpartition(row_array, -6)[:-6]] = 0`